# Connection Error In Cloud Function While Using ForEach

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, promise, google-cloud-functions

I want to update something on recent 1000 active users.

```
    var pic;
    var promises = [];
    var bot_user = "bot"

   return db.ref("userdata").child(bot_user).child("pic50").once("value").then((s)=>{
        pic = s.val()
        console.log(pic)
        return db.ref("userdata").orderByChild("lastactive").limitToLast(1000).once("value")
   }).then((snap)=>{
        console.log(snap)

        snap.forEach((usersnap)=>{
            var chatid;
            var user = usersnap.key
            console.log(user)
                if(bot_user.localeCompare(user)===-1){
                    chatid = bot_user+"-"+user
                }else{
                    chatid = user+"-"+bot_user
                }

                promises.push(                          
                        doSomething(data.after.val(),"text",chatid,s.val())
                )



            });

    });
   }).then(()=>{
    return Promise.all(promises)
   })
```

I tried running this function so many times. But the function gets killed after logging pic value from first return statement

And in log it gives a connection error.

How can I fix this issue :(

Comment: Your brackets are mis-matched: the ones on the final 3 lines are not connected to anything in the code you've posted so far

Comment: Damn it. Thank you for saving my day it works now @CertainPerformance

Comment: @Kim may I ask you to post the solution for your issue as an answer?